# What do setting do I use for xcode-select -switch?

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to install octave on macos mountain lion via the following:

```
sudo port install octave
```

However, the result of this command is always the following:

```
Error: 
Error: No valid Xcode installation is properly selected.
Error: Please use xcode-select to select an Xcode installation:
Error:     sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer # version 4.4
Error:
```

I've tried the suggested `sudo xcode-select -switch` command to no avail. The same error always occurs. Any ideas how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 20):

Did you install xcode or just the command line tools?

I installed just the command line tools and was able to trick some GEMS by using the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /usr/bin
```

I basically pointed them to the bin folder where my GCC lives.

Comment: Yes, I installed xcode and then installed the command line tools (actually, I initially only installed the command line tools, but then upgraded to mountain lion). I tried the suggested switch from your answer, but I have the same result.

Comment: Try doing a "which gcc" to find the path to your compiler.  Then sudo xcode-select -switch THAT_PATH.

Comment: The error message seems benign. I finally built octave, but needed to deleted a .h file that seemed not to be available that was causing a later error in the log output.

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

solved for me

Comment: Perfect! Do I need to do that every time I restart my computer?

Comment: No! you don't need to do on every restart.