# Trying to npm install jquery on OSX 10.8.4, but I'm getting xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected

Tags: xcode, macos, node.js, terminal, npm

Anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this.

```
$sudo npm install jquery -g --save 
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser/1.7.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/location/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/navigator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlparser/1.7.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/location/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/navigator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> contextify@0.1.6 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle/-/cssstyle-0.2.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssstyle/-/cssstyle-0.2.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.27.0.tgz
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch <path-to-xcode>, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.

gyp: Error 2 running xcodebuild
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:424:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.4.1
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.21
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/Users/Squirrel/tmp/npm-28408-2WYiLpGG/1385954909058-0.7763686068356037/package/lib/properties/webkitColumnBreakInside.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.1
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "jquery" "-g" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_Mongoose
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! path /Users/Squirrel/tmp/npm-28408-2WYiLpGG/1385954909058-0.7763686068356037/package/lib/properties/webkitColumnBreakInside.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /Users/Squirrel/tmp/npm-28408-2WYiLpGG/1385954909058-0.7763686068356037/package/lib/properties/webkitColumnBreakInside.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.27.0.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Squirrel/Documents/Code/Memry/Memry_Mongoose/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I came across this https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/19424 but I'm not using brew, and [What do setting do I use for xcode-select -switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716110/what-do-setting-do-i-use-for-xcode-select-switch) but my situation is slightly different, so I figured I'd ask before experimenting in terminal.  Thanks a bunch.  ^_^

UPDATE:  I installed Xcode from here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#  But I'm still getting this:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:43:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:46:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.21
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! tar pack Error reading /Users/Squirrel/tmp/npm-480-RYIbB0vg/1386026782247-0.8853209882508963/package
npm ERR! addLocalDirectory Could not pack "/Users/Squirrel/tmp/npm-480-RYIbB0vg/1386026782247-0.8853209882508963/package" to "/Users/Squirrel/.npm/cssstyle/0.2.7/package.tgz"
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```