# Can't Change Toolbar Color in Ti 3.1.3/iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm updating our Titanium mobile app for iOS 6.1 and I've updated the Ti SDK to 3.1.3. I'm compiling against iOS 6.1 and running in the iOS 7 Simulator (the reason for this is that we're not updating this app to iOS 7, we're writing a new app).

We have a toolbar that is supposed to be black in colour, however, now it's the iOS 6.1 default blue and I cannot get it to change.

I've tried using `window.setToolbar()` and also creating the toolbar and nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Code - what I originally tried:

```
var toolbar = Ti.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
    bottom: 0,
    borderTop: true,
    borderBottom: false,
    translucent: false,
    barColor: '#000000',
    animated: false
});

mainWindow.add(toolbar);
```

I've also tried:

```
mainMenuWindow.setToolbar(loggedOutBtns, {
    animated: false,
    barColor: '#000000',
    translucent: false 
});
```

and also tried setting the barColor property on the window itself:

```
mainMenuWindow.barColor = '#000';
```

Incidently, the nav/title bar at the top stays blue too in tabgroups and navigation windows.

Comment: Try setting barColor property on window object. Check KitchenSink code where barColor property is used: https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/common/MashupsWindow.js#L47

Comment: @daniula, thanks for your comment; I'd tried that before, and just tried it again, no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this was XCode 5. Even though I was compiling against iOS 6.1, XCode 5 was making it impossible to change the `barColor` property.

I installed XCode 4.6 again and compiled against iOS 6.1, using the iOS 6.1 simulator and the barColor displayed black like it was supposed to.

References to the following links helped me with my investigation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424373/379636
- http://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/how-to-get-back-the-ios-6-sdk-after-upgrading-to-xcode-5/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2774865/379636
- [What do setting do I use for xcode-select -switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11716110/379636)